# CKEditor missing toolbar icons

Tags: css, ckeditor

This is happening randomly out in the field. I am embedding the editor in a ASP.Net MVC application. When users clear their cache and restart the browser, it works again. Any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you used chromes dev tools or firebug in firefox to see if there is something funky going on with the image/css that's passed? Maybe it's not completing the request or if you have a compressor it may be breaking their css. I know for CKeditor we have a rule to ensure our css compressor doesn't touch it.

Comment: If that's the case, why would clearing the Cache fix it?

Comment: Don't know, just think that inspecting the elements and seeing what the browser says about their css/images could be pretty helpful info. If the browser has the image and all the css is applied properly and you don't have conflicting styles perhaps this is a setup issue with the specified machine/browser version issue, but it can't be narrowed down until we know if it's a network issue or not first. I've seen stranger things.

Comment: I've seen this issue in two cases only: on Opera right after it was opened and when icons strip or `ckeditor.js` file was cached so one was incompatible with the other (`ckeditor.js` contains position of icons in sprite).

Comment: I have seen this issue before, clearing the browser cache fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

You must convince your browser to clear it's cache for the icons.png image.

Go to htt://yoursite.com/path/to/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png

and then use Ctrl+F5 or Cmd+Shift+R (mac users) to tell your browser to not use the cache and fetch a new one, which will then be stored in the cache.

You CANNOT do this from the editor page for some reason, probably by the way that the css and image is loaded. And for me, this trick only worked in Firefox and not Chrome. However, if in Chrome you do Shift+Ctrl+N (new incogneto window) then go to your editor, you'll see that it is working. That's how your visitors will see it UNLESS they have the icons.png image cached in there browser as well. **The only way to fix this is to change the URL of the image**, which will require replacing the new url in the CSS file (it's the background image for all the buttons).

Comment: You can just clear browsing data in Chrome with just 'Images / Files' checked. +1 though as your reply helped me out.